# Using answers environments inside commands

Tags: macros, environments, answers

I use package answers for putting answers or hints to problems at the end of a document. I wonder if it is possible to use the environment for solutions inside a command. But the straightforward way:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{answers}

\newtheorem{problem}{Problem}
\Newassociation{sol}{Sol}{solutions}
\newcommand{\shortsol}[1]{\begin{sol} #1\end{sol}}

\begin{document}    
    \Opensolutionfile{solutions}
    
    \begin{problem}
    This is problem.
    \shortsol{42}
    \end{problem}
        
    \Closesolutionfile{solutions}
    
    \section*{Solutions}
    \input{solutions}
\end{document}
```

leads to the error:

```
Runaway argument?
! File ended while scanning use of \next.
<inserted text>
                \par
```

I would appreciate if someone tells me if such a thing is possible. (I am trying to use solutions environments inside commands mainly for compatibility reasons. I have some other documents where the problems are written using commands, e. g. `\problem{Statement}{Result is 42}`.)

Comment: Can you show some output. How you want to see it.

Comment: Basically you can't have `sol` in the argument to a command, because it needs to do verbatim-like business.

Comment: Thank you. I wanted to have the result same as if I would write `\begin{sol}42\end{sol}` instead of `\shortsol{42}` and that works for me.